# keras layers machine learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I am having problem in shape, how could i resolve this?What can I do ?

> File "run_demo.py", line 116, in main
>       model = get_crfrnn_model_def()
>
> File "./src/crfrnn_model.py", line 70, in get_crfrnn_model_def
>       score_fused = Add()([score2, score_pool4c])
>
> ValueError: Operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3, 34, 4) (3, 34, 3)

```
def get_crfrnn_model_def():
    channels, height, weight = 3, 500, 500

    # Input
    input_shape = (height, weight, 3)
    img_input = Input(shape=input_shape)

    # Add plenty of zero padding
    x = ZeroPadding2D(padding=(100, 100))(img_input)

    # VGG-16 convolution block 1
    x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='valid', name='conv1_1')(x)
    x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv1_2')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='pool1')(x)

    # VGG-16 convolution block 2
    x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv2_1')(x)
    x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv2_2')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='pool2', padding='same')(x)

    # VGG-16 convolution block 3
    x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv3_1')(x)
    x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv3_2')(x)
    x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv3_3')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='pool3', padding='same')(x)
    pool3 = x

    # VGG-16 convolution block 4
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv4_1')(x)
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv4_2')(x)
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv4_3')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='pool4', padding='same')(x)
    pool4 = x

    # VGG-16 convolution block 5
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv5_1')(x)
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv5_2')(x)
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv5_3')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='pool5', padding='same')(x)

    # Fully-connected layers converted to convolution layers
    x = Conv2D(4096, (7, 7), activation='relu', padding='valid', name='fc6')(x)
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
    x = Conv2D(4096, (1, 1), activation='relu', padding='valid', name='fc7')(x)
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
    x = Conv2D(3, (1, 1), padding='valid', name='score-fr')(x)
    print(x)
    # Deconvolution
    score2 = Conv2DTranspose(3, (4, 4), strides=2, name='score2')(x)
    print(score2)
    # Skip connections from pool4
    score_pool4 = Conv2D(3, (1, 1), name='score-pool4')(pool4)
    score_pool4c = Cropping2D((5, 5),name='score-pool4c')(score_pool4)
    print('asd')
    print(score_pool4c)
    score_fused = Add()([score2, score_pool4c])
    score4 = Conv2DTranspose(3, (4, 4), strides=2, name='score4', use_bias=False)(score_fused)

    # Skip connections from pool3
    score_pool3 = Conv2D(3, (1, 1), name='score-pool3')(pool3)
    score_pool3c = Cropping2D((9, 9))(score_pool3)

    # Fuse things together
    score_final = Add()([score4, score_pool3c])

    # Final up-sampling and cropping
    upsample = Conv2DTranspose(3, (16, 16), strides=8, name='upsample', use_bias=False)(score_final)
    upscore = Cropping2D(((31, 37), (31, 37)))(upsample)

    output = CrfRnnLayer(image_dims=(height, weight),
                         num_classes=3,
                         theta_alpha=160.,
                         theta_beta=3.,
                         theta_gamma=3.,
                         num_iterations=10,
                         name='crfrnn')([upscore, img_input])
    model = Model(img_input, output, name='crfrnn_net')
    return model
```

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.engine.topology import Layer
import high_dim_filter_loader
custom_module = high_dim_filter_loader.custom_module


def _diagonal_initializer(shape):
    return np.eye(shape[0], shape[1], dtype=np.float32)


def _potts_model_initializer(shape):
    return -1 * _diagonal_initializer(shape)

class CrfRnnLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, image_dims, num_classes,
                 theta_alpha, theta_beta, theta_gamma,
                 num_iterations, **kwargs):
        self.image_dims = image_dims
        self.num_classes = num_classes
        self.theta_alpha = theta_alpha
        self.theta_beta = theta_beta
        self.theta_gamma = theta_gamma
        self.num_iterations = num_iterations
        self.spatial_ker_weights = None
        self.bilateral_ker_weights = None
        self.compatibility_matrix = None
        super(CrfRnnLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        # Weights of the spatial kernel
        self.spatial_ker_weights = self.add_weight(name='spatial_ker_weights',
                                                   shape=(self.num_classes, self.num_classes),
                                                   initializer=_diagonal_initializer,
                                                   trainable=True)

        # Weights of the bilateral kernel
        self.bilateral_ker_weights = self.add_weight(name='bilateral_ker_weights',
                                                     shape=(self.num_classes, self.num_classes),
                                                     initializer=_diagonal_initializer,
                                                     trainable=True)

        # Compatibility matrix
        self.compatibility_matrix = self.add_weight(name='compatibility_matrix',
                                                    shape=(self.num_classes, self.num_classes),
                                                    initializer=_potts_model_initializer,
                                                    trainable=True)

        super(CrfRnnLayer, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, inputs):
        unaries = tf.transpose(inputs[0][0, :, :, :], perm=(2, 0, 1))
        rgb = tf.transpose(inputs[1][0, :, :, :], perm=(2, 0, 1))

        c, h, w = self.num_classes, self.image_dims[0], self.image_dims[1]
        all_ones = np.ones((c, h, w), dtype=np.float32)

        # Prepare filter normalization coefficients
        spatial_norm_vals = custom_module.high_dim_filter(all_ones, rgb, bilateral=False,
                                                          theta_gamma=self.theta_gamma)
        bilateral_norm_vals = custom_module.high_dim_filter(all_ones, rgb, bilateral=True,
                                                            theta_alpha=self.theta_alpha,
                                                            theta_beta=self.theta_beta)
        q_values = unaries

        for i in range(self.num_iterations):
            softmax_out = tf.nn.softmax(q_values, 0)

            # Spatial filtering
            spatial_out = custom_module.high_dim_filter(softmax_out, rgb, bilateral=False,
                                                        theta_gamma=self.theta_gamma)
            spatial_out = spatial_out / spatial_norm_vals

            # Bilateral filtering
            bilateral_out = custom_module.high_dim_filter(softmax_out, rgb, bilateral=True,
                                                          theta_alpha=self.theta_alpha,
                                                          theta_beta=self.theta_beta)
            bilateral_out = bilateral_out / bilateral_norm_vals

            # Weighting filter outputs
            message_passing = (tf.matmul(self.spatial_ker_weights,
                                         tf.reshape(spatial_out, (c, -1))) +
                               tf.matmul(self.bilateral_ker_weights,
                                         tf.reshape(bilateral_out, (c, -1))))

            # Compatibility transform
            pairwise = tf.matmul(self.compatibility_matrix, message_passing)

            # Adding unary potentials
            pairwise = tf.reshape(pairwise, (c, h, w))
            q_values = unaries - pairwise

        return tf.transpose(tf.reshape(q_values, (1, c, h, w)), perm=(0, 2, 3, 1))

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape
```

Comment: Your posted code has a syntax error (Missing a closing parenthesis on the third-to-last line). I wonder why that seems to happen frequently on SO when the askers supposedly have tested their code...

Comment: i added the parenthesis on that line...that was just a mistake during uploading this question...plz answer my doubt?why shape error is coming?

Comment: It is not coming for me, and I cannot help but suspect that was also "a mistake during uploading this question" (i.e. you accidentally fixed the bug).

Comment: I tried running my program again error still persists there and in my code there was no such syntax error

Comment: Yes, and in the code here there is no such shape error (for your information, I tested it by adding `from tensorflow.keras.layers import *` at the beginning; it ran all the way until `CrfRnnLayer`, which is after the error point you stated, and is a function you didn't provide in your question; my tensorflow version is 1.13.1). You haven't convinced me that your code is anything like the code in this question.

Comment: I EDITED MY QUESTION AND added CrfRnnLayer fuction in my code..please go through it

Comment: Now I encounter an error at `import high_dim_filter_loader`. Google gave me a [git repo](https://github.com/sadeepj/crfasrnn_keras/blob/master/src/high_dim_filter_loader.py) showing that it is a compiled module, and I'm not downloading and building the whole thing unless you can show me it is likely where the error comes from (which seems unlikely to me).

Comment: Have you even tried your own code you posted (the first snippet)?

Comment: actually my code is bit long so i didn't posted the whole code here....this is github link of my code plz go through it it will be of great help..go inside crfrnn2....https://github.com/ak121297/crfasrnnnew/tree/master

Answer (score 0):

OK I think I found the problem.

From the [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#conv2d):

> data_format: A string, one of `"channels_last"` or `"channels_first"`. The ordering of the dimensions in the inputs.  `"channels_last"` corresponds to inputs with shape  `(batch, height, width, channels)` while `"channels_first"` corresponds to inputs with shape `(batch, channels, height, width)`. It defaults to the `image_data_format` value found in your Keras config file at `~/.keras/keras.json`. If you never set it, then it will be "channels_last".

However, that is a dirty lie. Actually, the `image_data_format` can be configured from the [backend](https://keras.io/backend/). And two lines in your `run_demo.py` does exactly that:

```
from keras import backend as K
K.set_image_dim_ordering('th')
```

The best part? This seems to be some legacy API. When I googled the function, I can only find it in [Keras 1.2.2 documentation](http://faroit.com/keras-docs/1.2.2/backend/#set_image_dim_ordering) (The current version is 2.2.4).

Consider if you really need those two lines. Actually, remove the second line anyway. If you really need it, you can add in `K.set_image_data_format('channels_first')`, and probably you also need to change input shape to match:

```
# input_shape = (height, weight, channels)
input_shape = (channels, height, weight)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try using keras' `image_data_format` function:

```
from keras import backend as K

img_width, img_height = 500, 500

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    input_shape = (3, img_width, img_height)
else:
    input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)
```